# SyntaxError: Unexpected token . [Gulp]

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, node-modules

Пишу простенькое приложение на `Electron.js`. В нём использую gulp для компиляции sass. С помощью npm модули `gulp` и `gulp-ruby-sass` уже установил, написал скрипт, который уже ранее использовал. Но выдало такую ошибку:

```
/home/dima/Programming/JavaScript/Electron/gulpfile.js:4
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:138:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:199:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Вот содержимое файла gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    sass        = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return sass('sass/*.sass')
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
})

gulp.task('watch', ['sass'], function(){
  gulp.watch('sass/*.sass', ['sass']);
})

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

В интернете схожую проблему найти не смог, поэтому пишу тут. Буду благодарен любому ответу.

Comment: Запятую в конце предыдущей строки замените на точку с запятой.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Пол часа проверял и запятую не заметил)